# Pasar el resultado de Google Maps SearchBox al servicio de direcciones

Tags: javascript, html, html5, google-maps

He estado trabajando en un proyecto con la api de **`Google Maps`**, pero me surgieron algunos inconveniente en la parte del autocompletado y direcciones.

Me estado guiando con este **[ejemplo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions?hl=es-419)** que te da la misma pagina de la api de google:

Lo que quiero lograr es cambiar el `autocomplete` por `search box` para hacer búsquedas mas abiertas, he intentado varias veces pero no logro que funcione correctamente.

Esta es una captura del mapa funcionando con `autocomplete`, al momento de ingresar las direcciones en los dos cuadros de búsqueda se crea el trazo del punto **A** al punto **B**

[image: Mapa en funcionamiento con autocomplete]

Al momento de estar escribiendo el cuadro de búsqueda te genera opciones de autocompletado para que selecciones una, en el caso de que no se seleccione una opcion que te genera el autocompletado, no tomara la direccion como valida, esa es la razón por la que quiero cambiar `autocomplete` por `search box` ya que esta no genera ese inconveniente.

Este es un intento que trate de hacer para que hiciera el trazado como en la imagen de arriba (La cual usa `Autocomplete` para los cuadros de búsqueda), poner dos buscadores los cuales de vez de utilizar `Autocomplete` usen `SearchBox`, y se hiciera la comparación para crear la ruta del punto **A** al punto **B**.

Hasta ahí es hasta donde pude llegar, no se realmente a que se deba que no crea el trazo entre los puntos

```js
function initMap() {
       var origin_place_id = null;
        var destination_place_id = null
         var travel_mode = google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          mapTypeControl: false,
          center: {lat: 32.4999741, lng: -116.9721508},
          zoom: 13,
            disableDefaultUI: true
          
        });

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.

         var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
         var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
         directionsDisplay.setMap(map);


        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
         var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
         searchBox.bindTo('bounds', map);


        var input2 = document.getElementById('pac-input2');
        var searchBox2 = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input2);
         searchBox2.bindTo('bounds', map);


        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(input2);


        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {



          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
           searchBox2.setBounds(map.getBounds());


        });




          //Este es el buscador 1, aqui comienza su codigo 
        

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {

            return;
          }

          // Limpiar los marcadoress
          markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
          });
          markers = [];

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            if (!place.geometry) {
              console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
              return;
            }
            var icon = {
              url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Se crea el marcador en la ubicacion
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location
            }));

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);

          origin_place_id = place.place_id;
                    route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
                        directionsService, directionsDisplay);



        });





      //Este es el codigo del buscador 2, es una copia del anterior modificado con mi propias crencias :V

      var markers2 = [];

       searchBox2.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox2.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }

          // Limpiar los marcadores viejos
          markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
          });
          markers2 = [];

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            if (!place.geometry) {
              console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
              return;
            }
            var icon = {
              url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location
            }));

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);


           destination_place_id = place.place_id;
                    route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
                        directionsService, directionsDisplay)


        });



             //Creo que este el codigo para el codigo para el trazp de rutas xD 


             function route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
                    directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
                    if (!origin_place_id || !destination_place_id) {
                        return;
                    }
                    directionsService.route({
                        origin: {
                            'placeId': origin_place_id
                        },
                        destination: {
                            'placeId': destination_place_id
                        },
                        travelMode: travel_mode
                    }, function(response, status) {
                        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                        } else {
                            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                        }
                    });
                }









      }
```

```css
#map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
       .controls {
        margin-top: 10px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

      #pac-input,
      #pac-input2 {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 300px;
      }

      #pac-input:focus,
      #pac-input2:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      .pac-container {
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #type-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
      }

      #type-selector label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
```

```html
<input id="pac-input" class="controls center" type="text center" placeholder="Inicio">
  <input id="pac-input2" class="controls center" type="text center" placeholder="Fin">
    <div id="map"></div>
    
    
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDcglr0mL358bvGoBXuKhftNS1MBz76Zhg&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Comment: Vale, pero cual es el problema que te estás encontrando?

Comment: Bienvenido, según lo que entiendo es eliminar ese tipo de campo por el `search box` para así ejecutar la dirección, siendo valida la misma, así el usuario no haya seleccionado ninguna de las del auto-completado, Es eso, ¿no?.

PD: por cierto, muy buena formulada tu pregunta para ser la primera vez.

Comment: @frikinside 

En si el inconveniente que tengo es que quiero cambiar la clase Autocomplete por SearchBox en el código de los cuadros de búsqueda  
 
Aqui menciona los tipos de clases para hacer los autocompletados: 

(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete?hl=es-419#summary-of-classes)

Este es el ejemplo que estado usando para guiarme, utiliza la clase  Autocomplete, pero yo la quiero cambiar por SearchBox  
  
[https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions?hl=es-419]

Comment: Hola Rodolfo, eso me quedó claro. tal y como dice @PabloContreras la circunstancia la has dejado muy bien aclarada, no tengo dudas al respecto. Lo que me gustaría saber es que problemas te has encontrado a la hora de cambiar el autocomplete por el searchbox para intentar ayudarte a resolver ese problema.

Comment: @frikinside exactamente, es lo que no me quedo claro a mi tampoco. Rodolfo ¿Has intentado algo? si es así, actualiza la pregunta y agrega que has intentado.

Comment: @PabloContreras

Muchas gracias por comentar, no tengo mucha experiencia con programación, hice algunos intentos como yo creía que tal vez funcionarían pero no dieron resultados 
Actualizare la pregunta con lo que intente hacer para que vean mas a fondo

Comment: @frikinside

Muchas gracias por comentar, actualizare la pregunta con lo que he intentado hacer, realmente no tengo mucha experiencia en programación, trate de hacerlo como creía pero no funciono

Comment: @RodolfoZamoraLopez no importa que tan malo sea tu intento, lo importante es la intensión de hacerlo, yo no soy experto en el tema de programar, pero hago el intento y acá me han ayudado muchísimo. PD: por mas bobas que han sido mis preguntas, para otros, jamas me han ofendido.

Comment: @PabloContreras
He actualizado la pregunta con el código que he tratado de hacer, de verdad muchas gracias por los consejos ;)

Comment: Al ejecutar el código, la consola de stacksnippet muestra un error, pero no lo has descrito. Por favor lee la guía sobre cómo hacer preguntas de código que no funciona la cual se encuentra en [mcve]. Comenario al margen, me surgión la duda de cómo debuggar código en stacksnippet por lo que publiqué lo siguiente: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1825/65