# ¿Usar el servicio de indicaciones con SearchBox Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, google-maps

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con la API de `Google Maps`, me he estado guiando con este [**Ejemplo**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions?hl=es-419) que da la misma página de la API **"Place Autocomplete and Directions"**

Trate de hacer el mio guiándome con el ejemplo, remplazando la clase `Autocomplete` por la clase `SearchBox` pero no pude lograr nada....

Aquí les dejo el código que estuve haciendo, agregue dos cuadros de búsqueda que funcionan con la clase `SearchBox` pero no se como implementar correctamente el servicio de indicaciones para que funcione como el ejemplo anterior que tiene la clase `Autocomplete`.

Si me pudieran dar un ejemplo de como implementar ese servicio en el código que trate de hacer se los agradecería bastante.

```js
function initAutocomplete() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var input2 = document.getElementById('pac-input2');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    var searchBox2 = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input2);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input2);

    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
      searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
      searchBox2.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    var markers = [];
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
      var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

      if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
      }

      // Clear out the old markers.
      markers.forEach(function(marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
      });
      markers = [];

      // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      places.forEach(function(place) {
        if (!place.geometry) {
          console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
          return;
        }
        var icon = {
          url: place.icon,
          size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };

        // Create a marker for each place.
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          icon: icon,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location
        }));

        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          // Only geocodes have viewport.
          bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
      });
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
  }


var markers2 = [];
// Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
// more details for that place.
searchBox2.addListener('places_changed', function() {
  var places2 = searchBox2.getPlaces();

  if (places.length == 0) {
    return;
  }

  // Clear out the old markers.
  markers2.forEach(function(marker) {
    marker2.setMap(null);
  });
  markers2 = [];

  // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  places.forEach(function(place) {
    if (!place.geometry) {
      console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
      return;
    }
    var icon = {
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
    };

    // Create a marker for each place.
    markers2.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      icon: icon,
      title: place.name,
      position: place.geometry.location
    }));

    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      // Only geocodes have viewport.
      bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }
  });
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

```css
#map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
       .controls {
        margin-top: 10px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

      #pac-input,
      #pac-input2 {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 300px;
      }

      #pac-input:focus,
      #pac-input2:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      .pac-container {
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #type-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
      }

      #type-selector label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
```

```html
<input id="pac-input" class="controls center" type="text center" placeholder="Inicio">
  <input id="pac-input2" class="controls center" type="text center" placeholder="Fin">
    <div id="map"></div>
    
    
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDcglr0mL358bvGoBXuKhftNS1MBz76Zhg&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Comment: Agregué el stacksnippet. Como se mostraba el error `"{
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: searchBox2 is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 88,
  "colno": 1
}` agregué el código HTML y CSS de tu pregunta original. Ahora se muestra otro error. En un momento publicaré al menos una respuesta parcial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

A diferencia de `Autocomplete`, `SearchBox` puede devolver uno o varios resultados. Lo que requieres hacer es pasar un único resultado al servicio de direcciones.

## Ejemplo 1

En cuando a un ejemplo del uso de SearchBox, en [Places search box](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox?hl=es-419) (en español), se incluye un ejemplo "oficial". En este, se incluyen dos "subrutinas", una para el caso que se ha obtenga un único resultado, en el que el valor devuelto es un [escalar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalar_(inform%C3%A1tica)), y otra para el caso de resultados múltiples, en el que el valor devuelto es una matriz.

A continuación incluyo la adaptación del código de la referencia anterior. La adaptación consiste en asegurar que siempre se muestre la ubicación de un resultado. Para esto, en la subrutina que maneja el caso en que el resultado del `SearchBox` sea una matriz, se reemplazó `forEach` por `some` incluyendo al final del enunciado `return true`, para que sólo se ejecute para el primer resultado, esto, con la finalidad de realizar una adaptación mínima a su vez para fines de demostración.

> Notas:
>
> 1. Se tomó "prestado" el key de Google Maps API de la [pregunta original](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/64087/65) del OP.
> 2. Se cambió el centro del mapa, por "mero orgullo localista" :)

### Instrucciones para probar

Nota: Se recomienda probar usando la opción ampliada

1. Oprimir el botón "Ejecutar"
2. Probar los siguientes casos:

#### Caso "autocompletar"

Escribir `pizza` y seleccionar uno de las sugerencias con el ícono de marcador

#### Caso "buscar"

Escribir `pizza` y presionar <kbd>Intro</kbd>.

### Código

```js
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    // Coordenadas de Monterrey, N.L., México
    center: {lat: 25.685088, lng:-100.327482}, //{lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    /*
     * Para fines de minimizar las adecuaciones debido a que es este una demostración de adaptación mínima de código, se reemplaza forEach por some.
     */ 
    // places.forEach(function(place) {
    places.some(function(place) {
      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
      // some interrumpe su ejecución en cuanto devuelve un valor verdadero (true)
      return true;
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 300px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

.pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}

#type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#target {
  width: 345px;
}
```

```html
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDcglr0mL358bvGoBXuKhftNS1MBz76Zhg&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
     async defer></script>
```

---

## Ejemplo 2

He tomado el [ejemplo referido](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions?hl=es-419) por el OP y realizado el mínimo de modificaciones. La premisa fué evitar insertar nuevas líneas de código para lo cual se pusieron entre `/*` y `*/` las funciones  reemplazar y luego se escribieron las funciones reemplazantes, básicamente cambiar `Autocomplete` por `SearchBox` y `getPlace()` por `getPlaces()[0]`. Nótese que en el segundo caso se incluye el índice cero con la finalidad de utilizar el primer "place".

Las modificaciones fueron como las siguientes:

- en la siguiente línea se "reemplazó" `Autocomplete` por `SearchBox`

  ```
  var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places/*.Autocomplete*/.SearchBox(
    originInput, {placeIdOnly: true});
  ```
- en la siguiente línea se "reemplazó" `getPlace()` por `getPlaces[0]`

  ```
  var place = autocomplete/*.getPlace()*/.getPlaces()[0];
  ```

> Notas:
>
> 1. Se tomó "prestado" el key de Google Maps API de la [pregunta original](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/64087/65) del OP.
> 2. Se cambió el centro del mapa, por "mero orgullo localista" :)

### Instrucciones para probar

Nota: Se recomienda probar usando la opción ampliada

1. Oprimir el botón "Ejecutar"
2. Probar los siguientes casos:

#### Caso "autocompletar"

1. En la primer caja, escribir `pizza` y seleccionar una de las sugerencias con el ícono de marcador
2. En la segunda caja, escribir `museo` y seleccionar una de las sugerencias en el ícono de marcador

#### Caso "buscar"

1. Escribir `pizza` y presionar <kbd>Intro</kbd> y luego <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
2. Escribir `museo` y presionar <kbd>Intro</kbd>.

### Código

```js
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeControl: false,
    center: {lat: 25.6810658, lng: -100.3317736},//{lat: 33.8688, lng: -151.2195},
    zoom: 13
  });

  new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
}

 /**
  * @constructor
 */
function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
  this.map = map;
  this.originPlaceId = null;
  this.destinationPlaceId = null;
  this.travelMode = 'WALKING';
  var originInput = document.getElementById('origin-input');
  var destinationInput = document.getElementById('destination-input');
  var modeSelector = document.getElementById('mode-selector');
  this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places/*.Autocomplete*/.SearchBox(
      originInput, {placeIdOnly: true});
  var destinationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places/*.Autocomplete*/.SearchBox(
      destinationInput, {placeIdOnly: true});

  this.setupClickListener('changemode-walking', 'WALKING');
  this.setupClickListener('changemode-transit', 'TRANSIT');
  this.setupClickListener('changemode-driving', 'DRIVING');

  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST');

  this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(originInput);
  this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destinationInput);
  this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(modeSelector);
}

// Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
// Autocomplete.
AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupClickListener = function(id, mode) {
  var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
  var me = this;
  radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    me.travelMode = mode;
    me.route();
  });
};

AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(autocomplete, mode) {
  var me = this;
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);
  autocomplete.addListener(/*'place_changed'*/'places_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete/*.getPlace()*/.getPlaces()[0];
    if (!place.place_id) {
      window.alert("Please select an option from the dropdown list.");
      return;
    }
    if (mode === 'ORIG') {
      me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
    } else {
      me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
    }
    me.route();
  });

};


AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function() {
  if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
    return;
  }
  var me = this;

  this.directionsService.route({
    origin: {'placeId': this.originPlaceId},
    destination: {'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId},
    travelMode: this.travelMode
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      me.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
};
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#origin-input,
#destination-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 200px;
}

#origin-input:focus,
#destination-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#mode-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}

#mode-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<input id="origin-input" class="controls" type="text"
    placeholder="Enter an origin location">

<input id="destination-input" class="controls" type="text"
    placeholder="Enter a destination location">

<div id="mode-selector" class="controls">
  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-walking" checked="checked">
  <label for="changemode-walking">Walking</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-transit">
  <label for="changemode-transit">Transit</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-driving">
  <label for="changemode-driving">Driving</label>
</div>

<div id="map"></div>


<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDcglr0mL358bvGoBXuKhftNS1MBz76Zhg&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Comment: Agradezco el tiempo que toma por ayudarme, pero una duda que todavía no me queda muy clara, en el caso de que tuviera dos cuadros buscadores funcionando con la clase `Search Box`, como puedo implementar ese servicio de direcciones para que se haga el trazado del punto A al punto B como este ejemplo que da esta pagina:  
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions?hl=es-419

Comment: Señor Rubén, de verdad deseo darle enormemente las gracias por haberme ayudado bastante con ese código.
Llevaba 2 semanas tratando de hacer eso,  leí casi toda la documentación de la API, busque en diferentes foros y trate de buscar muchos ejemplos, pero no lograba hacer lo que quería.    
Soy estudiante de preparatoria (Llevo la carrera de programación)  y estoy realizando un proyecto WEB, no tengo mucha experiencia realmente, por lo que prefiero guiarme con ejemplos.

Comment: En agradecimiento me gustaría que viera el proyecto que estoy realizando con mi equipo, todavia le falta bastante pero de poco en poco lo estamos logrando: 

Es una pagina que servirá para el transporte publico, es como estilo UBER, pero para transportes públicos :) 

http://urbantapp.com/home.html

Comment: @RodolfoZamoraLopez: Me da gusto haberte ayudado. A falta de otras respuestas lo que corresponde es marcar esta respuesta como aceptada. Otra cosa que puedes hacer para mostrar tu agradecimiento es responder preguntas de otros usuarios del sitio. Más detalles sobre cómo dar las gracias en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1624/65

Comment: he estado usando las respuesta de este tema quisiera saber como alamcenar las coordenadas que se obtienen al seleccionar la nueva ubicacion como almacenarlas en una variable para luego por php poder guardarlas en una bd.Gracias

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/145494)

Comment: @moises Me da gusto que te sea útil esta respuesta. Como indica Raul, las preguntas de seguimiento deberían publicarse como nuevas preguntas. Te sugiero incluir un enlace a esta respuesta y poner otro comentario para avisar que lo has publicado.